# Cannot enter text into input field React

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a signup model form with a react-responsive-modal library. I wrote my Modal like this

```js
<Modal open={this.state.openCreateAlbum} onClose={this.onCloseModalCreate}>
  <div className="modal-body">
    <h2>Get Started Absolutely<span> Free!</span></h2>
    <span className="subtitle">No credit card needed</span>
    <form className="contact-form form-validate3" novalidate="novalidate">
      <div className="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="First Name" required="" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input className="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="pass" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" />
      </div>
      <input className="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-center" id="sign_up" type="button" value="Sign Up" />
    </form>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

Notice that for `First Name` field I'm not using `className=form-control` and for other fields, I'm using that `className`.

The problem I got is when I run that. I cannot enter text to email and password field but it's fine with the first name field. I don't know why and how to fix that. I followed a tutor video and he didn't have that issue.  Here is the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLQXEHDXnlU

Ps: Im using this library for Modal component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-modal

Comment: "I cannot enter text to email and password field" There is nothing shown when typing, or something else?

Comment: I've created a small JSFiddle with this code http://jsfiddle.net/eqwgnhf9/ it seems to behave normally here, no? If it does, I think there might be something with the Modal thing. Could you confirm JSFiddle is working as it should?

Comment: I cannot choose the email and password fields to type. the cursor didn't show up

Comment: Does it show on my JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes. But I copped your HTML code and replace with my but it didn't help

Comment: so the problem is likely to stay where the code you didn’t share here?

Comment: Do you think it because of the className ```form-control```? It's worked just fine after I removed the className. I be able to click into the field and type email or password.

Comment: :) it sounds like your template gets affected by `bootstrap` script